# VS Code uses wrong GitHub account to push commits

Tags: git, github

I recently made another GitHub account and have been facing a problem. The problem is that when I push commits to repository in the new account it always pushes using my other account.

I cleared the git credential in the Credential Manager(Windows) but even after that the issue still persists.

I am using a VS Code on Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for answers and trying a lot of them,
The one that worked for me:

1. Delete C:\Users\USER_NAME.gitconfig file
2. Set your username: git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
3. Set your email address: git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"

Voila, all done!

Comment: I'm glad someone else has had the same problem! Thank you for finding such a  simple solution.